# Retrieving image in form view from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a form view in which there is an `asp:Image` control :

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="ListStories" DefaultMode="ReadOnly" >
<ItemTemplate>
<table>
<tr><td><%#Eval("Subject") %></td></tr>
<tr><td><%#Eval("Story") %></td></tr>
<tr><td><%#Eval("UserName")%></td></tr>
<tr><td><asp:Image ID="ImageAuthor" runat="server"  /></td></tr>
</table>
</ItemTemplate>

</asp:FormView>
```

I am trying to set `ImageUrl` property from code behind like this:

```
Image imageAuthor = (Image)ListStories.FindControl("ImageAuthor") as Image;
        conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        cmdStories = new SqlCommand("SELECT Stories.UserName, Stories.Subject, Stories.Story, UserProfile.Photo FROM Stories INNER JOIN UserProfile ON Stories.UserName=UserProfile.UserName", conn);
        conn.Open();
        reader = cmdStories.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string userName = reader["UserName"].ToString();
            imageAuthor.ImageUrl = "~/ImageHandler.ashx?name"+userName ;
        }
        ListStories.DataSource = reader;
        ListStories.DataBind();
        conn.Close();
```

But it's giving me an error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Where am I getting wrong? 
Thanx

Comment: where is `reader` defined in this line
`reader = cmdStories.ExecuteReader();` are you omitting some code here..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE: I decleared the reader like this SqlDataReader reader;

Comment: please show all relevant code also state the exact line where you are getting the error please

Comment: When i remove this line imageAuthor.ImageUrl = "~/ImageHandler.ashx?name"+userName ; the error then not show

Answer (score 0):

Can you debug it? 
This error shows up when an object is null and you are trying to call something from it..
See if conn is ok by checking your conn string
imageAuthor can be null too...
Try remove "as Image" from "(Image)ListStories.FindControl("ImageAuthor") as Image"
You are already casting it to Image, no need for "as"
"as Image" elevates the chance for the object to be null

Comment: I removed "as Image" but still getting the same error and conn is ok because When i remove this line imageAuthor.ImageUrl = "~/ImageHandler.ashx?name"+userName ; the error then not shown

Comment: Like i said... imageAuthor still null...
You should set imageAuthor inside ListStories_DataBound

protected void ListStories_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Image img = (Image)ListStories.FindControl("ImageAuthor");
        
}